# TypeScript not seeing state parameters in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Why can't TypeScript see the state property `currentItem` in the `ZoneEditor` constructor, render function and so on? Because of that, TypeScript won't compile.

If it's important, I access ZoneEditor component via routing.

```
interface ZoneEditorState {
    currentItem: any;
}

class ZoneEditor extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, ZoneEditorState> {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { currentItem: null}; //here 
    }
   render(){
     return <XXX item={this.state.currentItem}/> //also here
   }
}
```

Errors:

`Error  TS2322  (TS) Type '{ currentItem: null; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'currentItem' does not exist in type '{ name: string; }'.`

and

`Error  TS2339  (TS) Property 'currentItem' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.`

Comment: What is the error you get when TypeScript won't compile?

Comment: You're setting this.state.currentItem as null. What are you expecting to get returned from it? What value do you want to give it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I updated post.

Comment: @Rodius it doesn't matter. I could also assign some `"test"` string, but it will be the same error... You could check error, I update post.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermimnd, accidentally (don't know how) I changed my `react types`... Lookup at state property.

```
// Base component for plain JS classes
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
class Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props?: P, context?: any);

    // Disabling unified-signatures to have separate overloads. It's easier to understand this way.
    // tslint:disable:unified-signatures
    setState<K extends keyof S>(f: (prevState: S, props: P) => Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
    setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
    // tslint:enable:unified-signatures

    forceUpdate(callBack?: () => any): void;
    render(): JSX.Element | null | false;

    // React.Props<T> is now deprecated, which means that the `children`
    // property is not available on `P` by default, even though you can
    // always pass children as variadic arguments to `createElement`.
    // In the future, if we can define its call signature conditionally
    // on the existence of `children` in `P`, then we should remove this.
    props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;
    state: Readonly<S>; // this line was looking like state: { name: string };
    context: any;
    refs: {
        [key: string]: ReactInstance
    };
}
```